# Getting 404 when using requests, but curl works fine

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests to pull down some JSON from a 3rd party portal.
Whenever i use requests i get a `'{"Message":"Path not found"}'` error
however running the command with cURL works fine.  Here is the cURL command:

`curl  https://blah.com/api/v1/nodes --header 'Authorization: Bearer my-long-token-base64'`

Trying to do this with python3 / requests i have:

```
#convert token to base64
base64_token = base64.b64encode(bytes(access_token, 'utf-8'))
#convert to str
base64_token = base64_token.decode("utf-8")

api = 'https://blah.com/api/v1/nodes'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + base64_token,
'Accept': 'application/json'}
nodes = requests.post(api, headers=headers)
```

whenever i run this the response is `'{"Message":"Path not found"}'`
I thought it might be something to do with the base64 token (which is required) but pretty sure i've got that part right because otherwise i get a 401.

any thoughts?

Comment: this website can help you converting cURL to python https://curl.trillworks.com

Comment: hmm so it works if i do: `headers = {
     ...:     'Authorization': 'Bearer mytoken'}` . but i want to pass the token in as a variable as it expires every 30 mins and i need to grab a new one